# Windows 8/Server 2012 style waiting/loading transparent GIF/APNG

Tags: animation, photoshop, gif, animated-gif

Where can I find a free waiting/loading transparent GIF/APNG animation similar to the one used in Windows 8/Server 2012 (i.e. when logging on, restarting, shutting down etc.)

I found one on http://cssload.net/

[the first loader in the loader selection list]

However this is a CSS based one and cannot be downloaded as a GIF/APNG.

Please help! I need one to use in one of my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can download the Gif loading transparent image which you want search http://preloaders.net/. Here is a [ink to the specific preloader](http://preloaders.net/en/search/windows%208).